# PHP - Sorting tables/ table filtering using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the free code of tablefilter.free.fr and have adding this to my code but it does not get executed.

I have added the html and javascript into https://jsfiddle.net/koalyptus/eCqG3/ and it works fine but when i use my page -> http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=Southwell it does not render for some reason although the same html is output.

below is the full code i use on the page to create the tables and add the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../table/tablefilter.js"></script>

<?php

//show today's meeting name

    if ($numrows > 0) {
        echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=' . urlencode($entry) . '" class="button green">' . $entry . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=' . urlencode($entry) . '" class="button jump">' . $entry . '</a>';
    }
    $met1 = array_values($meeting);

    if (array_shift($met1) == $entry && $venue ==""  || $venue == $entry)
    {
    echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue='.urlencode($entry).'" class="button green">'.$entry.'</a>';
    if ($venue =="")
    {
    $venue = array_shift($met1);
    }
    }
    else
    {



}
// pull the times for that meeting
$grabtracktimes = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT Racetime,Going,distance, COUNT(*) c FROM tom_cards Where Track = "' . $venue . '" GROUP BY Racetime HAVING c > 1;');
$meetingtime    = array();
echo "<br />";
while ($grabtodaystracktimes = mysqli_fetch_array($grabtracktimes)) {
    $meetingtime[] = $grabtodaystracktimes['Racetime'];
}
$meetingtime1 = array_unique($meetingtime);
foreach ($meetingtime1 as $entrytime) {
    if ($time == "") {
        $time = array_shift(array_values($meetingtime1));
    }
    if (array_shift($meetingtime1) == $entrytime and $time == "" or $time == $entrytime) {
        echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=' . urlencode($venue) . '&amp;time=' . $entrytime . '" class="button green medium">' . $entrytime . '</a>';
        if ($time == "") {
            $time = array_shift($meetingtime1);
        }
    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=' . urlencode($venue) . '&amp;time=' . $entrytime . '" class="button white medium">' . $entrytime . '</a>';
    }
}
echo "<br /><b>" . $venue . "(" . $time . ")</b>";


  $sqltodaystrack  = "";
     $sqltodaystrack2  = mysqli_query($db,  $sqltodaystrack );
$todaystrackleftorright = "";
$todaystrackspeed = "";
$todaystracksurface = "";
    while ( $sqltodaystrack3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltodaystrack2)) {

    $todaystrackleftorright = $sqltodaystrack3['Left_or_Right'];
    $todaystrackspeed = $sqltodaystrack3['speed'];
    $todaystracksurface = $sqltodaystrack3['surface'];
    }








$sql     = 'SELECT Race_Name,distance,going,surface FROM tom_cards Where Track ="' . $venue . '" and Racetime = "' . $time . '" group by Racetime  ';
$horses2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$first   = true;
while ($todayhorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horses2)) {
    if ($first == true) {
        // do something
        $first          = false;
        $todaysgoing    = $todayhorse['going'];
        $todaysdistance = miletofurlong($todayhorse['distance']);
        echo "<br /><br /><b>" . $todayhorse['Race_Name'] . "</b>";
        //add notes about the race course here
$sqlfortrack     = 'SELECT notes,Handicaps, Non_Handicaps FROM RaceCourse Where Course ="' . $venue . '"';
$fortrack = mysqli_query($db, $sqlfortrack  );

while ($fortrack2 = mysqli_fetch_array($fortrack)) {

echo "<br /><span style='font-size:11px'><b>Course Notes:</b> ".$fortrack2['notes']."</span><BR />";
//check if handicap or not and check for any course details

if (strpos($todayhorse['Race_Name'], 'Handicap') !== FALSE)
{
echo "<span style='font-size:11px'>".$fortrack2['Handicaps']."<span/>";
}
else
{
echo "<span style='font-size:11px'>".$fortrack2['Non_Handicaps']."</span>";
}



}
        echo " <br /><br />Distance: <b>" . miletofurlong($todayhorse['distance']) . "f </b>(" . $todayhorse['distance'] . ") Going: <b>" . $todayhorse['going'] . "</b>";
        $surface = trim($db->real_escape_string($todayhorse['surface']));
    }
}

echo "</div>";

echo "<table  id='table1'   style='border:0px;margin-top:50px;text-align: center ;'>";
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'><td>Horse</td><td>Form</td><td>History</td><td>OR/Class</td><td>MT Rating</td><td>Naps</td></tr>";
$sql     = 'SELECT horse,rp,ts,Naps,`OR`,Class,Jockeys_Claim,Trainer,Track FROM tom_cards Where Track ="' . $venue . '" and Racetime = "' . $time . '"';
$horses2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$loop    = 0;
while ($todayhorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horses2)) {
    $placed  = "";
    $data    = "";
    $horse   = trim($todayhorse['horse']);
    $jockeys = $todayhorse['Jockeys_Claim'];
    $trainer = $todayhorse['Trainer'];
    $class   = $todayhorse['Class'];
    $or      = $todayhorse['OR'];
    $rp      = $todayhorse['rp'];
    $ts      = $todayhorse['ts'];
    $naps    = $todayhorse['Naps'];
    if ($surface == "Turf") {
        $win          = 0;
        $runs         = 0;
        $place        = 0;
        $horsesplaced = ;
        $check        = "no";
        while ($pasthorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horsesplaced)) {
            $dbDate     = $pasthorse['Date'];
            $placeddata = intval($pasthorse['Place']);
            //add 1 to runs everyloop to show how many runs they have had
            $runs       = $runs + 1;
            //if the horse has won a race then mark it red and add 1 point to the win tally
            if ($placeddata == 1) {
                $placed .= "<b><span style='color:#8DB600'>" . $pasthorse['Place'] . "</span></b>";
                $win = $win + 1;
            } else {
                //if the horse was placed higher then 9th just add 0
                if (intval($pasthorse['Place']) > 9) {
                    $pasthorse['Place'] = 0;
                }
                //echo all the places
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == "PU") {
                    $pasthorse['Place'] = str_replace($pasthorse['Place'], 'PU', '<b>P</b>');
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == "F") {
                    $pasthorse['Place'] = str_replace($pasthorse['Place'], 'F', '<b>F</b>');
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == "2" or $pasthorse['Place'] == "3") {
                    $pasthorse['Place'] = str_replace($pasthorse['Place'], $pasthorse['Place'], "<span style='color:#8DB600'>" . $pasthorse['Place'] . "</span>");
                }
                $placed .= $pasthorse['Place'];
                // if runners are greater then 4 and less the 8 only 2 to place
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 4 and $pasthorse['Runners'] > 8) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 7 and $pasthorse['Runners'] > 16) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 15) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 4) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ($surface == "AW") {
        $win          = 0;
        $runs         = 0;
        $place        = 0;
        $horsesplaced = ;
        while ($pasthorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horsesplaced)) {
            $placeddata = intval($pasthorse['Place']);
            //add 1 to runs everyloop to show how many runs they have had
            $runs       = $runs + 1;
            //if the horse has won a race then mark it red and add 1 point to the win tally
            if ($placeddata == 1) {
                $placed .= "<b><span style='color:red'>" . $pasthorse['Place'] . "</span></b>";
                $win = $win + 1;
            } else {
                //if the horse was placed higher then 9th just add 0
                if (intval($pasthorse['Place']) > 9) {
                    $pasthorse['Place'] = 0;
                }
                //echo all the places
                $placed .= $pasthorse['Place'];
                // if runners are greater then 4 and less the 8 only 2 to place
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 4 and $pasthorse['Runners'] > 8) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 7 and $pasthorse['Runners'] > 16) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($pasthorse['Runners'] < 15) {
                    if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 4) {
                        $place = $place + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $winner  = "";
    $placed1 = "";
    if ($runs != 0) {
        $winner  = "(" . round(($win / $runs) * 100) . "%) ";
        $placed1 = "(" . round((($place + $win) / $runs) * 100) . "%) ";
    }
    $thetrack = horseontrack($horse, $venue, $db);
    list($corseruns, $corsewins, $corseplace) = explode("/", $thetrack);
    $sqlhorses   = "SELECT distance,Place,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`  WHERE  `Horse` = '" . $horse . "' order by distance + 0,
         substring_index(distance, 'm', -1) + 0";
    $horseplaced = mysqli_query($db, $sqlhorses);
    $data        = "";
    $dataleftorright = "";
    $dataspeed = ""; 
        $datasurface = ""; 
    $storage     = array();
    $storetrackdirection = array();
   $storetrackdirectionsurface= array();
   $storetrackspeed= array();
    while ($pasthorse = mysqli_fetch_array($horseplaced)) {
        // check to see if its distance is that of today
        $placetotals = 0;
        $wintotals   = 0;
        $test        = "";
        $placeddata  = intval($pasthorse['Place']);
        if ($placeddata == 1) {

        } else {
            if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 4 and $pasthorse['Runners'] < 8) {
                $test = "--between 5 and 7--" . $pasthorse['Place'];
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2) {
                    $placetotals = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 7 and $pasthorse['Runners'] < 16) {
                $test = "--Between 8 and 15--" . $pasthorse['Place'];
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3) {
                    $placetotals = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorse['Runners'] > 15) {
                $test = "over 15" . $pasthorse['Place'];
                if ($pasthorse['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorse['Place'] == 4) {
                    $placetotals = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // if the distance is the same
        // Take this outside of the if statements
        $mtfl = miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']);
        if ($mtfl == $todaysdistance) {
            $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $mtfl . "f</span></b>";
        } elseif (($mtfl >= $todaysdistance - 1) && ($mtfl <= $todaysdistance + 1)) {
            // You don't need to check for equality here - if you get here it is because
            // the values are not equal
            $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:#8DB600'>" . $mtfl . "f</span></b>";
        } else {
            $Horsedist = $mtfl . "f";
        }
        if (!isset($storage[$Horsedist])) {
            $storage[$Horsedist] = array(
                "win" => 0,
                "placed" => 0,
                "raced" => 0
            );
        }
        // Then increment if required

        // $data .= "<span style='font-size:10.5px'>".$Horsedist. " -Won:".$wintotals. " Placed:".$placetotals."  </span><br />";
    }
    $sqlhorsesgoing   = "SELECT going,Place,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`  WHERE  `Horse` = '" . $horse . "' order by going";
    $horseplacedgoing = mysqli_query($db, $sqlhorsesgoing);
    $datagoing        = "";
    $storagegoing     = array();
    while ($pasthorsegoing = mysqli_fetch_array($horseplacedgoing)) {
        // check to see if its going is that of today

        $placeddatagoing  = intval($pasthorsegoing['Place']);
        if ($placeddatagoing == 1) {

        } else {
            if ($pasthorsegoing['Runners'] > 4 and $pasthorsegoing['Runners'] < 8) {
                if ($pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 2) {
                    $placetotalsgoing = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorsegoing['Runners'] > 7 and $pasthorsegoing['Runners'] < 16) {
                if ($pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 3) {
                    $placetotalsgoing = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorsegoing['Runners'] > 15) {
                if ($pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorsegoing['Place'] == 4) {
                    $placetotalsgoing = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // if the going is the same
        // Take this outside of the if statements
        $mtfl1 = $pasthorsegoing['going'];
        if ($mtfl1 == $todaysgoing) {
            $Horsegoing = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $mtfl1 . "</span></b>";
        } else {
            $Horsegoing = $mtfl1;
        }
        if (!isset($storagegoing[$Horsegoing])) {
            $storagegoing[$Horsegoing] = array(
                "win" => 0,
                "placed" => 0,
                "raced" => 0
            );
        }
        // Then increment if required

    }


    $data = "<table class='tg' align='center' style='font-size:10.5px;'><tr><th style='padding-right:5px;'></th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Runs </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Wins </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Placed </th></tr>";
    foreach ($storage as $pony => $tab) {
        // $data .= "<span style='font-size:10.5px'>".$Horsedist. " -Won:".$wintotals. " Placed:".$placetotals."  </span><br />";
        if ($tab["win"] !== 0) {
            $distancewinners = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $tab["win"] . "</span></b>";
        } else {
            $distancewinners = $tab["win"];
        }
        if ($tab["placed"] !== 0) {
            $distanceplace = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $tab["placed"] . "</span></b>";
        } else {
            $distanceplace = $tab["placed"];
        }

    }
    $data .= "</table>";



    foreach ($storagegoing as $ponygoing => $tabgoing) {
                  if ($tabgoing["win"] !== 0) {
            $distancewinners = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $tabgoing["win"] . "</span></b>";
        } else {
            $distancewinners = $tabgoing["win"];
        }
        if ($tabgoing["placed"] !== 0) {
            $distanceplace = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>" . $tabgoing["placed"] . "</span></b>";
        } else {
            $distanceplace = $tabgoing["placed"];
        }


    //work out which courses the horse has ran at

 $horseplacedtracks  = "SELECT track,Place,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`  WHERE  `Horse` = '" . $horse . "'";
   $horseplacedtracks2  = mysqli_query($db, $horseplacedtracks  );
$track ="";
$leftorright = "";
$surface = "";
$speed = "";

 while ($pasthorsetracks  = mysqli_fetch_array($horseplacedtracks2 )) 
 {
 //remove (aw) and get the track name
$track = trim(str_replace("(AW)", "", $pasthorsetracks['track']));
//is the track left or right??


 // check to see if its going is that of today
        $placetotalstrack = 0;
        $wintotalstrack   = 0;
        $placeddatatrack  = intval($pasthorsetracks['Place']);
        if ($placeddatatrack == 1) {
            $placetotalstrack = 1;
            $wintotalstrack   = 1;
        } else {
            if ($pasthorsetracks['Runners'] > 4 and $pasthorsetracks['Runners'] < 8) {
                if ($pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 2) {
                    $placetotalstrack = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorsetracks['Runners'] > 7 and $pasthorsetracks['Runners'] < 16) {
                if ($pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 3) {
                    $placetotalstrack = 1;
                }
            }
            if ($pasthorsetracks['Runners'] > 15) {
                if ($pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 2 or $pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 3 or $pasthorsetracks['Place'] == 4) {
                    $placetotalstrack = 1;
                }
            }
        }



// check the track against the database and asign left or right
$grabtrackdetails  = "SELECT Left_or_Right FROM  `RaceCourse`  WHERE  `Course` = '" . $track . "'";
   $grabtrackdetails2  = mysqli_query($db, $grabtrackdetails );
while ($pastgrabtrackdetails  = mysqli_fetch_array($grabtrackdetails2 )) 
 {
$leftorright = $pastgrabtrackdetails['Left_or_Right'];
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (!isset($storetrackdirection[$leftorright])) {
            $storetrackdirection[$leftorright] = array(
              "win" => 0,
                "placed" => 0,
                "raced" => 0
            );
        }
        // Then increment if required
       $storetrackdirection[$leftorright]["win"] += $wintotalstrack;
    $storetrackdirection[$leftorright]["placed"] += $placetotalstrack;
        $storetrackdirection[$leftorright]["raced"] += 1;
         }






         // check the track against the database and asign left or right
$grabtrackdetailssurface  = "SELECT surface FROM  `RaceCourse`  WHERE  `Course` = '" . $track . "'";
   $grabtrackdetailssurface2  = mysqli_query($db, $grabtrackdetailssurface );
while ($pastgrabtrackdetailssurface  = mysqli_fetch_array($grabtrackdetailssurface2 )) 
 {
$surface = $pastgrabtrackdetailssurface['surface'];

if ($surface == "")
{
$surface = "Mix";
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (!isset($storetrackdirectionsurface[$surface])) {
            $storetrackdirectionsurface[$surface] = array(
              "win" => 0,
                "placed" => 0,
                "raced" => 0
            );
        }
        // Then increment if required
       $storetrackdirectionsurface[$surface]["win"] += $wintotalstrack;
    $storetrackdirectionsurface[$surface]["placed"] += $placetotalstrack;
        $storetrackdirectionsurface[$surface]["raced"] += 1;
         }


             $horsehistory  = "SELECT Date,track,Class,Distance,going,Place,Jockeys_claim,`OR`,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`  WHERE  `Horse` = '" . $horse . "' order by Date DESC";
   $horsehistory2  = mysqli_query($db, $horsehistory  );
$horseshistoryget = "<br />";

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tf<?php echo $loop; ?> = setFilterGrid("loop<?php echo $loop; ?>");
</script>
<?

$horseshistoryget .= "<table id='loop".$loop."' class='mytable'  align='center' style='font-size:10.5px;'><tr><th style='padding-right:5px;'></th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Course </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Class</th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Distance </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Going</th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Outcome </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> Jockey </th><th style='padding-right:5px;'> OR </th></tr>";

 while ($gethorsehistory  = mysqli_fetch_array($horsehistory2 )) 
 {

    //$horseshistoryget .= "<tr style='height:18px;   border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'><td  style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" .$gethorsehistory["Date"] . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["Track"] . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["Class"]  . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["Distance"]  . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["Place"]  . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["Jockeys_claim"]  . "</td><td style='border-top:1pt solid black;  border-bottom:0pt solid black;'>" . $gethorsehistory["`OR`"]  . "</td></tr>";
$timestamp = strtotime($gethorsehistory["Date"]);
 $newDate = date('d.m.y', $timestamp); 

 // check if the value is the same as today and bold it



$horseshistoryget .= "<tr><td>". $newDate. "</td>";



//check what todays course speed and surface is like
$todayscourseprofile = "SELECT speed,surface from RaceCourse where course = '".$venue."'    ";
  $todayscourseprofile2  = mysqli_query($db, $todayscourseprofile  );
   $todayscoursespeed = "" ;
 $todayscoursesurface = "";
 while ($gettodayscourseprofile  = mysqli_fetch_array($todayscourseprofile2 )) 
 {
 $todayscoursespeed = $gettodayscourseprofile["speed"] ;
 $todayscoursesurface = $gettodayscourseprofile ["surface"];
 }

//check if venue has the same profile as this one 
$trackprofie = trim(str_replace("(AW)", "", $gethorsehistory["track"]));
 $allcourseprofile = "SELECT speed, surface from RaceCourse where course = '".$trackprofie."' ";

  $allcourseprofile2  = mysqli_query($db, $allcourseprofile  );

 while ($getallcourseprofile  = mysqli_fetch_array($allcourseprofile2 )) 
 {
   $allcoursespeed = "" ;
 $allcoursesurface = "";
 $allcoursespeed = $getallcourseprofile["speed"] ;
 $allcoursesurface = $getallcourseprofile ["surface"];
 } 
 //if they match colour them


 if($todayscoursespeed ==  $allcoursespeed and  $allcoursesurface == $todayscoursesurface  )
 {
 if ($todayscoursespeed <> "" and $todayscoursesurface <> "")
 {
  $showtrack = "<span style='color:#336600 '>".$gethorsehistory["track"]."</span>";
  }
  else
  {
   $showtrack = $gethorsehistory["track"];
  }
 }
 elseif ($todayscoursespeed ==  $allcoursespeed)
 {

 if ($todayscoursespeed <> "")
 {
 $showtrack = "<span style='color:#996600 '>".$gethorsehistory["track"]."</span>";
  }
  else
  {
   $showtrack = $gethorsehistory["track"];
  }
 }
 elseif($todayscoursesurface ==  $allcoursesurface)
 {
  if ($todayscoursesurface <> "")
 {
 $showtrack = "<span style='color:#CC3300 '>".$gethorsehistory["track"]."</span>";
  }
  else
  {
   $showtrack = $gethorsehistory["track"];
  }

 }
 else

 {
 $showtrack = $gethorsehistory["track"];
 }




 if ($gethorsehistory["track"] == $venue)
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td><b>" .  $showtrack.  "</b></td>";
}
else{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" .  $showtrack."</td>";
}





if ($gethorsehistory["Class"] == "Class".$class)
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td><b>" . $gethorsehistory["Class"] . "</b></td>";
}
else
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" . $gethorsehistory["Class"] .  "</td>";
}



if (miletofurlong($gethorsehistory["Distance"]) ==  $todaysdistance)
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td><b>" . miletofurlong($gethorsehistory["Distance"]). "f" . "</b></td>";
}
else
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" . miletofurlong($gethorsehistory["Distance"]). "f" . "</td>";
}

if ($gethorsehistory["going"]  ==  $todaysgoing)
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td><b>" . $gethorsehistory["going"] .  "</b></td>";
}
else{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" .$gethorsehistory["going"] . "</td>";
}

if ($gethorsehistory["Place"] == 1){
$pastplace = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>".$gethorsehistory["Place"]."</span></b>";
}
else{
$pastplace = $gethorsehistory["Place"];
}
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" . $pastplace ."/". $gethorsehistory["Runners"].  "</td>";



if ($gethorsehistory["Jockeys_claim"] ==  $jockeys)
{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td><b>" .$gethorsehistory["Jockeys_claim"].  "</b></td>";
}
else{
$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" . $gethorsehistory["Jockeys_claim"] .  "</td>";
}

$horseshistoryget .= "<td>" .$t1. $gethorsehistory["OR"]  .$t2. "</td></tr>";


    }


$horseshistoryget .= "</table><br />";

    //does the jockey only have one ride today???
    echo "<tr valign='top'><td  >";
    echo "<b><span style='font-size:12px'> " . $horse . "</span></b> <sup><span style='font-size:10px;color:gray'><abbr title='Days Since Last Race'>" . horselastrace($horse, $db) . "</abbr> </span><b><span style='font-size:10px;color:red'><abbr title='Beaten Favourite'>" . horsebeatenfav($horse, $db) . "</abbr></span></sup></b>
<br /><span style='font-size:10.5px'><abbr title='Jockey'>J: " . $jockeys . "</abbr><abbr title='Jockey Win rate last 4 months'> (" . round(howhotisjockey($jockeys, $db)) . "%)</abbr> " . " <abbr title='Jockey Win rate on horse'>(" . round(howhotisjockeyonhorse($jockeys, $db, $horse)) . "%)</abbr><abbr title='Jockey rides today'> " . jockeyridestoday($jockeys, $db) . "</abbr>
<br /><abbr title='Trainer'> T: " . $trainer . "</abbr> <abbr title='Trainer Win rate last 4 months'>(" . round(howhotistrainer($trainer, $db)) . "%)</abbr> <abbr title='Trainers horses out today'>  " . trainersridestoday($trainer, $db) . "</abbr> </span></td>";
    echo "<td ><span style='font-size:11px'><abbr title='P = Pulled Up , F = Fell'> " . $placed . "</abbr></span> <span style='font-size:10.5px'> <abbr title='Win Percent'> " . $winner . "</abbr> <abbr title='Place Percent'>" . $placed1 . "</abbr></span>  </td>";
  //  echo "<td ><span style='font-size:11px'>".$dataleftorright.$dataspeed.$datasurface."</span></td>";
   // echo "<td >" . $data . "<br /></td>";
  //  echo "<td >" . $datagoing . "<br /></td>";
echo "<td >".$horseshistoryget."</td>";

    echo "<td ><span style='font-size:11px'><abbr title='class and highest winning OR'> " . classtop2($horse, $db, $or, $class) . "</abbr></span> </td>";
    echo "<td ><span style='font-size:11px'><abbr title='Mr-Tipster speed rating'> " . round((($rp + $ts) / 2)) . "</abbr> </span></td>";
    echo "<td ><span style='font-size:11px'>" . $naps . "</span></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $loop = $loop + 1;
}
?>
       </table>    
    </div>
                </body>

                </html>
```

Comment: Create a small, very simple php page and test that. Try echoing something really simple, and then making it slightly more complex each time.

Comment: I see `/*` on line 15 but if I copy the code into Notepad++ and format as PHP, Notepad++ doesn't ever find a close for that comment. And I can't find one thumbing through quickly. I'm not experienced in PHP but with you saying "it does not get executed," I'm wonder if maybe it is because the code is commented out. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry like i said i had to remove some of the code to make it fit and left it in - re edited

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? if it doens't render anything, it can either be that there is a syntax error somewhere, a parse error or an Exception. try adding: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very beginning.

Comment: I've never used tablefilter in the past, whenever I want to manipulate tables using javascript my go to library is [Mottie's Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Comment: @doveyg, with all due respect to Emma, the problem is not the library. The problem is the code. And to be blunt, Emma, you won't get any help unless you shrink the code to a test-case that is 100 lines or less.